# Unable to search record with whitespace using LTRIM & RTRIM

Tags: sql-server

Table

```
| patientFirstName | patientMiddleName | patientLastName |  startdate |    enddate |    
|------------------|-------------------|-----------------|------------|------------|    
|          Patient |              Demo |            Test | 2018-09-02 | 2018-09-08 |    
|             John |               Doe |            Demo | 2018-09-02 | 2018-09-14 |    
|         Demo User|                   |                 | 2018-09-18 | 2018-09-28 |
```

In the above table I'm trying to search for user "Demo User" and my search input is "demouser". I tried trimming the whitespace but still I don't see the result.

```
DECLARE @searchInput varchar(10)
DECLARE @startTime DATE
DECLARE @endTime DATE
SET @searchInput = 'demouser'
SET @startTime   = '2018-09-18'
SET @endTime     = '2018-09-28'

SELECT * FROM PatientDemoTable
WHERE (@startTime IS NULL OR startdate >= @startTime)
AND   (@endTime   IS NULL OR enddate   <= @endTime)
AND   ( LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchInput)) IS NULL OR patientFirstName like 
'%'+LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchInput))+'%'
     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchInput)) IS NULL OR patientMiddleName like 
'%'+LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchInput))+'%'
     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchInput)) IS NULL OR patientLastName like 
'%'+LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchInput))+'%')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/93ce1/33

Note : I cannot use TRIM as i'm on older SQL Server

Comment: Add the tag related to the version you are using, this will help more.

Comment: Why not just use the `REPLACE(patientFirstName, ' ', '') like 
'%'+LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchInput))+'%'` form? It would simply remove all spaces from the column. You can do the same for tabs if it seems like an additional requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot use TRIM as i'm on older SQL Server

Well, you can use **[REPLACE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function (Start with SQL Server 2008) as belew:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    patientFirstName VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('     Patient       '),
('     John          '),
('     Demo User     ');

SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE UPPER(REPLACE(patientFirstName, ' ', '')) = UPPER('demouser');
```

If you are looking for other columns as well you need just to add `OR` like:

```
WHERE UPPER(REPLACE(patientFirstName, ' ', '')) = UPPER('demouser')
OR UPPER(REPLACE(patientMiddleName, ' ', '')) = UPPER('demouser')
OR UPPER(REPLACE(patientLastName, ' ', '')) = UPPER('demouser');
```

Comment: OP is wild carding the search, you have a hard =

Comment: @JohnCappelletti If you have on col1 `Dem` and col2 `OUser` this will bring the row in your solution, which I don't think the OP want it :) I think about it dude

Comment: In that, I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sargable, but should return the desired results

```
....
WHERE (@startTime IS NULL OR startdate >= @startTime)
AND   (@endTime   IS NULL OR enddate   <= @endTime)
AND   charindex(@searchInput,replace(concat(patientFirstName,'-',patientMiddleName,'-',patientLastName),' ',''))>0
```

**Note**: the `'-'` is optional, they just prevent bleed overs

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
SET @searchInput = 'demouser'
SET @searchInput = LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@searchInput)))


SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
    LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE([patientFirstName],' ','')))        patientFirstName
,   LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE([patientMiddleName],' ','')))   patientMiddleName
,   LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE([patientLastName],' ','')))     patientLastName
,   [startdate]
,   [enddate]
FROM PatientDemoTable
) D
WHERE
( 
        ISNULL(@searchInput,LOWER(patientFirstName))    = LOWER(patientFirstName)
    OR  ISNULL(@searchInput,LOWER(patientMiddleName))   = LOWER(patientMiddleName)
    OR  ISNULL(@searchInput,LOWER(patientLastName))     = LOWER(patientLastName)
)
AND 
(
        ISNULL(@startTime, startdate) >= startdate
    AND ISNULL(@endTime, enddate) <= enddate
)
```

`LTRIM()` AND `RTRIM()` are just for insurance of removing white spaces, while `REPLACE()` will also remove any space. `LOWER()` will make all letters in small caps (this is just a work around of database collation, if the collation is a case sensitive).

THE `ISNULL()` will replace `@searchInput` with the columns data, so it'll bring all data if is it NULL (another work around that will avoid using LIKE expressions.)